# RenderAs PDF with Bootstrap

Tags: pdf, bootstrap, renderas

I'm building out a Bootstrap website in Salesforce and I now have a requirement to allow the users to download some of the pages as PDFs. Unfortunately, when I use `renderAs="PDF"`, I get this error:

```
Error accessing PDF resource 
Resource url = https://cs22.salesforce.com/resource/1430422148000/Bootstrap_3_1_1/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
```

The resource does exist. I don't use the glyphicons on this page, but I'd hate to remove them from the static resource when I might use them elsewhere. What can I do?

For reference, this line will cause the error (when `renderAs="PDF"`):

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap_3_1_1, 'bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}" />
```

---

**Update**: We ended up dropping PDF support because of the limitations on what Salesforce can turn into a PDF—and look good.

Comment: How are you linking to the resource on your page? Notice the resource is timestamped: `.../resource/1430422148000/...`.

Comment: It's a Static Resource, so I'm using `$Resource` to link the Bootstrap CSS, and that relatively includes the glyphicons.

Comment: can you share the portion of code that errors out ?

Comment: I don't get that error when I change a Bootstrap page to `renderAs="PDF"`. (The PDF rendering of Bootstrap is not surprisingly pretty poor though.) I presume you have double checked that the font files are present at "css/../fonts"?

Comment: @Keith Correct. The files do exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bootstrap css file change the relative paths to the glyphicons fonts to some CDN e.g. change

../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot

to

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot

Comment: The Salesforce server doesn't handle external requests well. Seems there might be a [workaround using Documents](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xH1IAI), but I haven't tried it as we dropped this feature.