# External URL is not accessible unless whitelisted

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, pdf, bootstrap

Following is the error I am getting on using bootstrap for PDF file generation.

> External URL =
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
>   is not accessible unless whitelisted (appserverPath =
>   http://ap2.salesforce.com, request URL =
>   http://my-instance.force.com/apex/PDFDemo)

I changed relative font path with a CDN link as suggested [HERE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/77114/24076), but still getting the same error.

Change made in bootstrap -

From-

```
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

To -

```
src: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

Following is my code -

```
<apex:page  docType="html-5.0" renderAs="PDF">
  <!-- Adding CSS -->
  <!-- <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS092, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" /> -->
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css')}" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')}" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty new to Salesforce so there's a good possibility that I got this wrong (i would add this as a comment instead of an answer if I had enough rep to do that).

Basically, what comes to my mind is that you need to add the Request URL to "Remote Sites".

Check this out - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm&language=en

Comment: I remove the font from `glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot` to Arial in bootstrap now the error is - `PDF generation failed. Check the page markup is valid.`  http://pastebin.com/uf3UmjTd

Comment: Go to the link below and check the last comment about the large CSS files:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AaVAIA0

Comment: you are right I shorten the bootstrap file to around 600 and its working...pretty useless :(

Comment: Wonder if it's possible to divide that one large css into multiple short ones and include them one by one? Maybe then everything will work as expected.

Comment: I dont think its working as if I am using it as VF, then bootstrap classes applied but in PDF not working :(  This is the css file I am using http://pastebin.com/ctesBTGc and this is the code http://pastebin.com/20Gkcy1q

Comment: This is how they are coming, Chk the screenshots http://i.imgur.com/ncchiMU.png & http://i.imgur.com/C52RI2n.png

Comment: I can't point a finger at what's going wrong and why the PDF is rendered differently than VF. All I can do now is point you to SF documentation - [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Formating-VisualForce-Page-rendered-as-PDF-1327108686696&language=en_US). There's a link on that page to a guide on how to use CSS to format PDF files, it might be useful to you.